# Phrase usage: Dipping ones toe (into sth.)

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrases

***You start to grow by first dipping your toe.***

Can this sentence be used as a motivational quote?
If dipping your toe into sth. means testing it out, carefully approaching it and growth is considered personal growth. Is it a legitimate sentence or *dipping your toe* can't go without *into sth.* in this context?

Comment: It's not motivational, it's common sense, which will unlikely get you moving... The correct phrasing I believe is "to dip one's toe *in/into* sth" unless it's an order

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I understand. I'm wondering if I may sacrifice "something" for the sake of rhyme.

Comment: So you perceive this sentence as an order?

Comment: No, a (somewhat unusual) command would be "Dip your toes! Now!"

Comment: Aha, ok. I thought maybe it sounds like "You, start to grow!". (Btw., It's all just for one cheesy LinkedIn post, I don't plan to inspire anyone.)